# How to select second calendar button using selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I am using this code to select the calendar `button`, I have one more calendar button on the same page, this code selects only first calendar button not the second one.

```
driver.findElement(
    By.cssSelector("button.ui-datepicker-trigger.ui-button[aria-label='Show Calendar']")).click();
```

Second html tag:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create `cssSelector` more specific to locate unique element as below :-

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span[id*='ddate'] button.ui-datepicker-trigger.ui-button[aria-label='Show Calendar']")).click();
```